# How are auto_increment keys handled in INSERT (SELECT * FROM...)

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have `table1` and `table2` in MySQL. Both have a primary `auto_increment` key `id`.

If the table schemas match and I do `INSERT INTO table1 (SELECT * FROM table2)` what happens with regards to the new rows inserted in to `table1`? Do they keep their old `id` values and generate conflicts when a row from `table1` has the same `id`? Are new values generated by auto_increment? Does it depend on the storage engine or locking?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can insert into an auto-increment column and specify a value. This is fine; it simply overrides the auto-increment generator.

If you try to insert a value of NULL or 0 or `DEFAULT`, or if you omit the auto-increment column from the columns in your INSERT statement, this activates the auto-increment generator.

So, it's fine to `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2` (by the way, you don't need the parentheses). This means that the id values in `table2` will be copied verbatim, and `table1` will *not* generate new values.

If you *want* `table1` to generate new values, you can't do `SELECT *`. Either you use null or 0 for the id column:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT 0, col1, col2, col3, ... FROM table2;
```

Or else you omit the column from both the INSERT statement's column list and the SELECT statement's select-list:

```
-- No id in either case:
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM table2;
```

Before you ask, there is no syntax in SQL for "select * except for one column". You have to spell out the full list of column names you want to insert.

Comment: Isn't there an option that allows/disallows insert of 0 as a value? (Regarding your 2nd paragraph)

Comment: Yes, [SQL_MODE=NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html), otherwise we could never insert a literal zero value into an AI column. If you use this SQL mode, NULL still works to activate the AI generator, or omitting the column works too.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Regarding your last paragraph, after getting the subresult `select * from table`, is there no way to operate on this subresult to remove its first column?

Comment: @Pacerier, if I understand correctly, you're asking if `select *` can mean `select * except for the first column`. The answer is no. `select *` always requests *all* the columns from that table. If you want a subset, you must spell out the columns you want.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Hmm, I was thinking of [pivoting the table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/632951) to do vertical where clauses, then pivoting it back e.g. `select*from transpose(select*from(transpose(select*from table where Id=1))where col_name<>Id)` or perhaps more succinctly as `select*from table where Id=1 and $col<>Id`, what do you think?

Comment: @Pacerier, the pivot/transpose functions I have seen do not make the column headers into a column. So your made-up syntax does not work. I don't know why you're trying to do acrobatics to avoid using `select *`. This problem has a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 4):

The id from the select will be the same value inserted into the table. This will result in an error if you're trying to duplicate existing rows.

> **Bill Karwin:** Before you ask, there is no syntax in SQL for "select * except for one column".

This can be achieved with some creativity:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO <table> SELECT null, 
    ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = '<database>' 
    AND table_name = '<table>' 
    AND column_name NOT IN ('id')), ' 
from <table> WHERE id = <id>');  

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

This will result in the new row getting an auto incremented id instead of the id from the selected row.

Comment: Clever, but to me, that counts as spelling out the full list of column names you want to insert.

Comment: Well it's mysql automatically spelling it out versus doing it manually. If you have tables with a lot of columns, it'll prevent you from missing one or misspelling a few.